# How to check if specified id does not exist in two tables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have two relational tables.

#### table 1 staffs_items

```
item_id   int(11)
staff_id  int(11)
```

#### table 2 entries_items

```
item_id   int(11)
entry_id  int(11)
```

I want to check if an item_id does not exist in both tables.

like this:

```
SELECT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM staffs_items AS si WHERE si.item_id = 1 ) AS exist;

+-------+
| exist |
+-------+
|     1 |
+-------+

SELECT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM entries_items AS ei WHERE ei.item_id = 1 ) AS exist;

+-------+
| exist |
+-------+
|     0 |
+-------+
```

I want to run those queries in a one liner.

If item_id does not exist in either table, I want to return 0 (false).

How can I do that?

Comment: `SELECT EXISTS(query to table1) + 2 * EXISTS(query to table2)`. 0 - in none, 1 - in 1st, 2 - in 2nd, 3 - in both.

Comment: It sounds like very unique query. But I think I will forgot what means "2" when I leave my project. So I'll see that off this time. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just place both exists subqueries into a single select:

```
SELECT
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM staffs_items WHERE item_id = 1) AS exists_staff_item,
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM entries_items WHERE item_id = 1) AS exists_entries_item;
```